# Video output options of the CLI players?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, xorg, vlc-media-player, mplayer

Just thought I'd jot this down while I have the problem: On a computer that apparently has a problem with having X11 use graphics acceleration, I experience (understandably) problems playing video (which can otherwise be decoded by the players). Comparing the "triumvirate" of `vlc`, `ffplay` and `mplayer` in this context, I found I can use:

```
mplayer -vo x11 test.flv
```

... and then `mplayer` uses a "plain" X11 surface to draw the video properly - apparently at the expense of doing software decoding of video (and using a LOT of cpu for it!)

My question is - are there comparable options for the same in `vlc` and `ffplay`? I already looked through `man ffplay` and `vlc -H --help-verbose | less`, but I cannot find anything: `ffplay` doesn't seem to allow any video output (as in "drawing surface") control; `vlc` apparently does, but not for "plain" X11 (implying software decoding).  Still, it would be nice to have this confirmed one way or the other.